# Clean memory after using a large list of data in WCF Service

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, memory-management, event-log

I have a WCF client and I connect to a WCF server hosted in a Windows service. In the service I read the last day entries from the Security event log. Then I parse the entries and create my own `List<Data>` which I return to my WCF client to display it in a DataGrid. The problem is that in the Security event log I have 30000 entries and after I parse every entry I create 30000 of new objects of type `Data`. This type is a class with 15 string properties which contains the details from the messages from the event log. After the whole process, the memory usage of the Windows service goes up with 60-70MB. Once I send this large set of data to the client, how can I lower the memory used by Windows service from 70-80MB to the default 10MB ?

Here is my code:

```
public List<Data> GetConnections()
{        
   var eventLog = new EventLog("Security");
   var fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
   var entries = (from EventLogEntry e in eventLog.Entries
                   where (e.InstanceId == m_EventNumber) && e.TimeGenerated >= fromDate orderby e.TimeGenerated
                   select e).ToList()
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeGenerated);

   var items = new List<Data>();
   foreach(var item in entries)
   {
      var nData = ParseMessage(item.Message);
      if (nData != null)
          items.Add(ruleData);
   }
   return items;
}
```

Comment: What is the settings for service [SessionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.sessionmode.aspx) set by [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.aspx)?

Comment: SessionMode = SessionMode.Required

Comment: Okay, and `ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode`?

Comment: InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single

Comment: Try to play with this parameter. Single means a singleton. PerCall will destroy service object with all instances it references. What can gain some GC performance. Buy also may not.

Comment: I need to be singleton because the duplex communication and the data should be syncronized between the server and the client. Also, the server does some callbacks in some situations, so the singleton is a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more efficient code: only one loop instead of two, less objects to collect by GC.

```
var q = from EventLogEntry e in eventLog.Entries
        where (e.InstanceId == m_EventNumber) && e.TimeGenerated >= fromDate orderby e.TimeGenerated
        order by e.TimeGenerated desc
        let r = ParseMessage(e.Message)
        where r != null
        select r;

return new List<Data>(q);
```

Comment: `ParseMessage` can apparently return `null`, which is not desired in the resulting list.

Comment: Thank you for your improvement. It improves the speed.

Answer (score 1):

Does your memory consumption keep going up with every call to the service? If you call the service once a minute, do you have 60*70MB of memory use after an hour? If not, then you may not have a memory leak. You shouldn't need to take any action.

Comment: The memory is slightly increasing with the every call. I have found a workaround. Before making the query I call: GC.GetTotalMemory(true); This will force the old data to be garbage collected. Also, after 1 minute, I call the same GC.GetTotalMemory(true); and the memory of the Service goes back to 10MB. As I see, there is no memory leak, but the the objects can reside in memory pretty much time after they are used. Thank you very much. I can't let the GC do it's job automatically, because  if my users will see 100MB in Task Manager for the service for a long time, they will not like this.

Comment: Teach your users, instead of breaking your application by forcing unnecessary garbage collections.